# Bitbucket (on premise) is showing wrong Jenkins build status in PR - green but still running

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, bitbucket-server

**Setup**

I have a bitbucket server (6.2.0) and a Jenkins (2.190) build server.

On Jenkins side I have a Bitbucket Team/Project (delivered by https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-branch-source-plugin).

**Issue**

Sometimes the bitbucket build status of the PullRequest is not correct.
E.g. a build is currently running and bitbucket says it's a successful build. It links to to the "success" build in Jenkins but this build is still running.

Did I understand anything wrong or is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: I can't say what's happening for sure in Jenkins but I can tell you that Bitbucket Server's build status API is dead simple and unlikely to be the problem - you POST your desired build status (e.g. "SUCCESSFUL") to a commit resource, and that's about it. Bitbucket is merely showing the build status it has been told to show, so I would dig deeper into the Jenkins plugin you're using. FWIW Atlassian provides an official Jenkins plugin for Bitbucket Server: https://plugins.jenkins.io/atlassian-bitbucket-server-integration/ … Full disclosure I work at Atlassian in Developer Tools support!

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. I am confused about the plugins to connect to Bitbucket server. Currently I use `bitbucket-branch-source-plugin` with `Bitbucket Team/Project`. I thought this is the most current way (before I used `Stash Pullrequest Builder`). If you have an overview how `Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin` and `Bitbucket Server Integration` complement each other other have same functionalities would be great. This artice does not mention `Bitbucket Server Integration` https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000053051-How-to-Trigger-Multibranch-Jobs-from-Bitbucket-Server-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.
The issue was with the `Jenkinsfile`.
In the very beginning I had this line in my scripted Jenkinsfile:

```
currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"
```

At the end I corrected this status to FAILURE if neccessary.
So I removed this line in the beginning.

But it seems that a "Bitbucket Team project" send this status as soon as it's set back to Bitbucket.

I was missleaded by other code old snippets in our Jenkinsfile like

```
notifyBitbucket(buildStatus: 'INPROGRESS')
```

which had no effect on Bitbucket and are legacy from bitbucketNotifier Plugin (https://github.com/jenkinsci/stashnotifier-plugin)

The only thing what I don't like that in jenkins the running build is red initially but who wants to see the jenkins as long it is green in the end and bitbucket has the right status ;-):
[image]